# store URL global before we redirect

Tags: redirect, urls, cookies, wp-redirect

I am using `wp_redirect ( get_permalink ( $post->ID ) );` to redirect users to variable (random) posts I need to know if the user redirected to current post from specific URL or not

Is it possible to store the current URL before redirecting then pass it to the redirected post

what I need to do is

```
if user  reach this page from www.example.com/?p=123 
// do some thing

else
// another staff
```

I tried to use `wp_get_referer();` but it's not what I need

Answer (score 2):

How about adding parameters to the URL you redirect to:

```
wp_redirect ( add_query_arg("utm_source", $thispage, get_permalink ( $post->ID ) ));
```

and then checking the parameter on the target page?

Comment: Good  Idea , but I don't need it to be parameter so I tried to add anchor but unfortunately PHP don't fetch any thing after # , BTW your code working fine

Comment: Yeah, the hash part of any URL ("#...") is client side only. How about setting a cookie with the path set to the target page (to help avoid race conditions)?

Comment: this is exactly my question, but I have no Idea about how to do it

Comment: `setcookie("origin", $thispageId, 0, preg_replace("!^https?://[^/]+!", "", get_permalink($thatpage)));` before the redirect, then look at `$_COOKIE["origin"]`. This won't play nice with caching, but if that's not a problem, this should work just fine.

Comment: @adnan What’s wrong with a parameter? This sort of thing is what they’re for

Comment: @Jacob Peattie , it's 2nd option for me,

Comment: @janh2 thanks I will check it , but is there is any solution for cache?

Comment: Depends on what your goal is. If you can do it on the client side with JS, that's cache friendly.